# How to write command in bash?

Tags: bash

How to write command in bash ? ( for user test if program return segmentation fault, remove lock file. )

```
su -c "/usr/local/bin/test || if $? > 0 then rm -fr /var/run/test.lock " test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
su -c "/usr/local/bin/test || if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then rm -fr /var/run/test.lock; fi" test
```

or

```
su -c "/usr/local/bin/test || [ $? -gt 0 ] && rm -fr /var/run/test.lock" test
```

Comment: dimba is absolutely right an has as well provided the correct solution. Another one with `if` could be `su -c "if ! /usr/local/bin/test; then rm -fr /var/run/test.lock; fi"`

Answer (score 4):

$? in double quotas is expanded before `su` command is executed.

You don't need to check $? - right part of `||` is executed only if test fails:

```
su -c "/usr/local/bin/test || rm -fr /var/run/test.lock " test
```